# Android stop specified IntentService

Tags: android, multithreading, service, intentservice

I've have develop an android application with an IntentService.

This IntentService does nothing more like a fileupload.

I just want to implement the functionality to upload multiple "file-upload-threads".

The problem is to stop one specified "file-upload-thread".

For example:

1. User choose ten files from the device and upload these.
2. A notification is created to gives the user "transfer-feedback".
3. While the thread is working the user can choose other files to upload.
4. Another notification is created but does not start until the first thread is done.

Is it possible to implement a "cancel-functionality" for the user to cancel the first thread and the second thread start automatically?!

Maybe is it better to user an Service instead of an IntentService?

Answer (score 0):

IntentServices are designed to run-one-at-a-time. Of course you could cancel your IntentService since in inherits from [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: Thank you @Rüdiger. Do you how i can stop one the IntentServices from a notification?

Comment: to control your IntentService use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyService extends IntentService {
    public static volatile boolean shouldStop = false;
    public MyService() {
        super("My Service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        doStuff();
    }

    private void doStuff() {
        // do something 

       // continue doing something

// put those checks wherever you need
       // check the condition
       if (shouldStop) {
           stopSelf();
           return;
       }


   }
}
```

And from your activity code you can change the state of the boolean flag to true if you want to stop the service. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you @Silvans. So is it possible to stop one IntentService from a notification?

Comment: yes you can stop it from anywhere as we have taken boolean as public static so you can access from your notification code as well.

Comment: Perfect Silvans! But i think that the hole "IntentService-Que" is canceling? I just want stop just one of the X threads... Maybe i misunderstood you :(

Answer (score 0):

An IntentService is designed to stop itself only when all the requests present in the work queue have been handled.As per docs,IntentService class "Stops the service after all of the start requests are handled, so you never have to call stopSelf()

In case you want to cancel requests,you can probably use volley and cancel previous requests
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#cancel